# Merging categories with small n (or median splits on categorical variables)

Tags: categorical-data, median

I've found a lot of resources on why median splits on continuous variables are generally bad, but I haven't found anything on merging levels from already categorical variables, specifically when some levels have very small numbers of responses.

For example, I asked for age in a survey as a categorical variable with the following levels: 18-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55-64, 65+. The first and last levels had very few responses, so I did a median split into 18-34 and 35+ (I could have done 3 groups, but I chose to do 2). This binary variable along with a few others were then used as predictors in a linear mixed effects model.

Is this sort of manipulation prone to the same issues as median splits on continuous data? Is it any more legitimate because my sample wouldn't have been big enough to make accurate analyses of all category levels? Can you suggest any papers or other resources that discuss this type of manipulation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the respondents who are 35?

Also you may want to review the literature on Small Area Estimation, depending on exactly what you are trying to do.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_area_estimation

Comment: I wasn't totally accurate in my OP. I combined the levels to create the following two: 18-34 and 35+.